# I get this error: E can not be converted to E.

Tags: java

Sorry, I am not sure how to present my problem clearly.
I have a stack and I want to implement a method to remove all duplicates of an object of type E by using my removeDuplicates() method.
The method invokes another method in the class called removeAll(), which finds all objects of type E and removes them if found in the stack.
I understand that the problem is that the compiler can not tell whether the keepPile stack of type E is of the same type E in the original stack. 
Once again I apologize for the confusing language. But can anyone help me find a solution?

```
public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> { 
//push() adds object to stack
//pop() removes object from stack
...    
    public E peek() { //returns object without removing from stack
        if (isEmpty()) {
          throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E result = (E) stack[size - 1];
        return result;
    }

    public void removeAll(E obj){
        ArrayStack<E> keepPile = new ArrayStack<>();
        ArrayStack<E> throwAwayPile = new ArrayStack<>();
        while(!this.isEmpty()){
            if(obj.equals(this.peek())){
                throwAwayPile.push(this.pop());
            }else{
                keepPile.push(this.pop());
            }
        }
        while(!keepPile.isEmpty()){
            this.push(keepPile.pop());
        }
    }

    public static <E> void removeDuplicates(Stack<E> stack){
        ArrayStack<E> keepPile = new ArrayStack<>();
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            keepPile.push(stack.pop());
            removeAll(keepPile.peek()); //problem is thrown here. The types are not guaranteed to be the same
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static <E> void removeDuplicates` - why is this a static, generic method, and why does it call the non-static `removeAll`?

Comment: This is a homework assignment and I was asked to do it in that very specific way.

Comment: What object do you want to call the `removeAll` method of, then?

Comment: The removeAll(E obj) removes all obj in the main stack. The keepPile is just acting as a temporary storage stack. I am sequentially adding items from the top of the main stack to the keepPile and removing the duplicates from the main stack by peeking at the keepPile

Comment: The question is: how does this compile? Perhaps the code is `stack.removeAll(keepPile.peek());`?

Comment: Lol. Yea, I forgot to write that in. You're the winner! I suppose user2357112 was getting at that, but I was a bit thick headed to realize it. Thaks to you both!